# Unexpected results while passing arrays as parameters in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, reference

I am trying to get used to using pointers but i am struggling a bit whilde passing them into functions as parameters. I read that arrays are passed by reference to functions therefore a code like this can change the array elements(Assuming a valid array is given):

```
void f(int *b)
{
  b[2]=1;
}

in main:
f(validArray);
```

However even though we pass the pointer  this doesn't seem to work;

```
void foo(int *b)
{
  b=b+2;
}

in main:
f(validArray);
```

doesn't move the pointer a step further.
Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. So you may not write for example

```
validArray = validArray + 2;
```

As for this pseudocode snippet

```
void foo(int *b)
{
    b=b+2;
}

in main:
foo(validArray);
```

then the pointer `b`  is a local variable of the function. So within the function the value of `b` is changed due to this statement

```
    b=b+2;
```

But this does not have an effect on the passed argument.

Instead you could write

```
void foo( int **b )
{
    *b = *b + 2;
}

int main( void )
{
    int validArray[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    int *p = validArray;
    foo( &p );
    printf( "%d\n", *p );
}
```

In C the term "passing by reference" means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. So dereferencing the pointer in a function you can change the pointed object. Pointers are the same objects. So if you want to change an original pointer you have to pass a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: f( &p ); should be foo( &p );

Comment: @Jonaswg Thanks. It was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

> I read that arrays are passed by reference to functions

That's not quite right. When you pass an array to a function, a pointer is passed. Changing the pointer won't change the array. You can, however, change the array via the pointer. That's why the `b[2]=1;` works. `b` is still just a pointer that was passed as a copy though, so `b=b+2;` won't change the array.

> It doesn't move the pointer a step further. Why is that?

It does move `b` ahead, but `b` is local to `foo` and is gone afterwards without changing the array. If you did this, for instance.

```
void foo(int *b)
{
    b=b+2;
    b[2]=1;
}
```

Then this will change `validArray[4]`.

Comment: ohh because i am dereferencing the pointer b by using [] i can change the array indeed now i see.

Answer (score 2):

```
b[2]=1;
```

is essentially

```
*(b+2) = 1;
```

which means its changing the data in the address `(b+2)`

---

```
b=b+2;
```

this means you are making `b` point to `2` elements next to what b was pointing before, which does not affect the data in the address of the pointer `b`, hence does not change the data in the array `validArray`